# DROP column and update BigQuery table containing streaming data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with streaming data. The table is being populated using a Dataflow job. Recently I updated my Dataflow pipeline by removing `Column_B` of the two columns shown below:

```
| Column_A | Column_B  |
|----------|-----------|
| Anna     | Chicago   |
| John     | Houston   |
```

---

But now my updated table contains the same number of columns as before, but with new data intended for `Column_B` replaced with `null`. Here´s an example of my updated pipeline:

```
| Column_A | Column_B  |
|----------|-----------|
| Anna     | Chicago   |
| John     | Houston   |
| Michael  | null      |
| Cecilia  | null      |
| Ronald   | null      |
```

My table is partitioned on timestamp. I am wondering if there´s a way to completely drop `Column_B` and looking for suggestions regarding how to (if I should) do that. Also, how would that impact my table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity assume your current table is named as `table_name`.

STEP 1. In the query settings select following option:

```
Set a destination table for query results
```

Step 2. Run following query to save the result set as a table:

```
SELECT *
EXCEPT(Column_B)
FROM table_name
```

Table created in Step 2 is named as `table_name_modified`. This table will act as a backup for your data.

Step 3. Drop `table_name`. Once you drop the `table_name` rename `table_name_modified` to `table_name`.

Now you have updated the table to exclude Column_B Dataflow won't be populating nulls anymore.

Comment: Thank you, @SAL. But since my table contains streaming data in this case, I am afraid I might lose some data while renaming tables.

Comment: Ohh. Then the best bet would be to create a view on top of existing table and just ignore columns which are not required. Additionally you can refer this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas Deleting a column directly is not possible, work around are required. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas